# Java: Mnemonics and Unicode

Tags: java, unicode, mnemonics

I am currently having problems with unicode and mnemonics in a Java SE application.
In the menu bar i added a menu with the name "ФMnemonicUnicodeTest" and the first letter is set as Mnemonic.
 
The integer value which is set as mnemonic is "1060".

- Windows 7
- English system language
- Java SE 6, 32bit
- Russian / Russian keyboard layout
- Physical russian keyboard

Code:

```
menu.setMnemonic((int)(text.substring(index+1, index+2).charAt(0)));
```

The menu is displayed correctly (mnemonic character is underlined).
But the mnemonic does not expand the menu with "ALT + Ф" (the key is displayed at the physical keybpard as "AФ").

My question is: Why is the mnemonic not working and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Long time I haven't been doing this, but I think that for menu shortcuts, you need to use one of the virtual key values.

You might get more information in the KeyEvent javadoc.

Comment: But this would mean that mnemonics are only applicable for the letters which are available as virtual keys.
When I catch the keyevent which is thrown when I type "ALT+Ф" the key character is the right, but the keycode is 65 (for A).

Comment: I am using resource files for internationalization and they define the translation and the mnemonic which should be used. I would have to find the corresponding virtual key for a unicode character dynamically and the character which is used as mnemonic is not underlined if I use the virtual key which is thrown.